# Cannot get data over POST

Tags: php, html, post

In html file I've got the following part of code:

```
<!-- Contact Form -->


<section>
        <form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
                <div class="row 50%">
                        <div class="6u">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="6u">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row 50%">
                        <div class="12u">
                                <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></texta$
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                        <li><input type="submit" class="style1" value="Send" /></li>
                                        <li><input type="reset" class="style2" value="Reset" /></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </form>
</section>
```

And in php file sendmail.php, i have:

```
<?php
    $address = $_POST['contact-email'];
    $body = $_POST['contact-message'];
    $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
    echo($address);
    echo($body);
    echo($name);
```

?>

When I try to run this form it doesn't do anything. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: `$_POST['contact-email'];` refers to the `name` of the element, not the `id`, so you could have `<input type="text" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email" />` instead

Answer (score 6):

Because, in posted file, you are not accessing with proper names:

You are trying to access those posted variables through their `id` not with `name`.

When a form is posted, its variables can be aceessible via their `name` attibutes as they key of `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

`id` and `class` are are not considered anywhere in `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`.

```
$address = $_POST['contact-email'];
$body = $_POST['contact-message'];
$name = $_POST['contact-name'];
```

Should be

```
$address = $_POST['email'];
$body = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: @Nikita: Can you please mark my answer as solution if it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use field name rather then field id.

such as:

```
 $address = $_POST['email'];

  $name = $_POST['name'];

  echo($body);

  echo($name);
```